# Node itself can serve static files without express or any other module..?

Tags: node.js

I am beginner in the field of node js.No idea how to send simple request from url 
Like :- http://localhost:9999/xyz/inde.html
my file hierarchy is

```
server.js
xyz(folder)-
          |->index.html
```

And get the html page from my server.Which is running at post 9999

```
var http = require("http");
function onRequest(request, response) {
console.log("Request received.");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9999);
console.log("Server has started.");
```

I know i can send string(having html template) from node js server and send it in response but how to send file without express and any other external module.
Thanks

Comment: nodejs does NOT serve any files/URLs by default.  You have to start a server and then install some code (your own code or one of the many libraries built for doing this) for handling whatever paths/filenames you want your server to respond to.  If you want, you can write this code yourself from scratch, but since it's been written and tested many times by others, most people use a pre-buit module and then configure that module to serve the files they want served.

Comment: Thanks,So node itself cannot provide any module for files.

Comment: nodejs is modular.  There exist many modules for serving files.  You select one of those modules, load it (probably from NPM) and use it or you write your own code from scratch.  That's how nodejs development works and all the pre-built modules are one of its great strengths as a platform.  I have no idea why you're trying to avoid using pre-developed tools that already solve your problems.

Comment: nodejs server without a framework: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's ridiculous to attempt to create a node application without `npm` dependencies, because the base of nodejs is just that -- a base. Unless you feel like implementing entire protocols, you're better off using a minimal, well maintained `npm` module that does that for you. That said, here is the very basic thing you asked for (without MiME, eTags, caching, etc, etc):

```
var basePath = __dirname;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(basePath, req.url));
    stream.on('error', function() {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    });
    stream.pipe(res);
}).listen(9999);
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to path traversal. Put the code above in server.js. Then try http://localhost:9999/server.js

Comment: Next, run:
telnet localhost 9999[enter]
GET /../../../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1[enter]
[enter]

Comment: Of course it is. It blatantly uses `path.join` and reads without validation of anything. It is already said that this is a ridiculous and very basic thing. Anyone would be much better of using a library that takes care of all that. But, if you feel it deserves an edit, by all means, go for it.

Comment: I believe that this is for mere informational purpose to gain knowledge on internal workings of modules of Node. Any ways thanks for answer, its of great knowledge.

Comment: express is not a  "minimal, well maintained npm module". it is an entire framework.

Answer (score 7):

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

function send404(response){
  response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Error 404: Resource not found.');
  response.end();
}

const mimeLookup = {
  '.js': 'application/javascript',
  '.html': 'text/html'
};

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if(req.method == 'GET'){

    let fileurl;
    if(req.url == '/'){
      fileurl = 'index.html';
    }else{
      fileurl = req.url;
    }
    let filepath = path.resolve('./' + fileurl);

    let fileExt = path.extname(filepath);
    let mimeType = mimeLookup[fileExt];

    if(!mimeType) {
      send404(res);
      return;
    }

    fs.exists(filepath, (exists) => {
      if(!exists){
        send404(res);
        return;
      }

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType});
      fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(res);

    });

  }
}).listen(3000);
console.log("Server running at port 3000");
```

Comment: the code snippet gives an error. it would really help to get some explanation about whats going on.

Comment: zaheer has a couple custom things that he didn't elaborate on.  Instead of `send404(res)`, you can just do `res.writeHead(404); res.end();`.  Also, the object `mimeTypes` is some custom object he used, which holds whatever mime types he considers valid.

Answer (score 3):

its very simple, node already provide fs module from which u can read that html
file and append
on response obj like this:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
//here is the code required
fs.readFile("./xyz/index.html", (err,fileContent) =>
{
  response.end(fileContent);
});
```

but the problem here is you will only get the HTML document
not the resources inside that HTML files which are stored in
different folders like if you have this code in your index.html

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />`

this index.css will not be allowed by the node server.
But i guess your question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the assertion in the accepted answer:

> "It's ridiculous to attempt to create a node application without npm dependencies"

as having zero dependencies allows you to deploy an app to a system that runs node by just copying the javascript file(s), and without running `npm install`.

An example of when I found this useful in real life was writing a public API to compute the amount of income tax a business needs to withold from an employee's pay. You can read all about this [fascinating topic here](https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Schedule-1---Statement-of-formulas-for-calculating-amounts-to-be-withheld/) but in essence I had an api that was passed a gross income and returned how that gross income should be split between net income and tax.

I did this with one solitary index.js file, no package.json, and need to `npm install`:

index.js:

```js
http = require('http');
url = require('url');
const port = 80; // make this a number over 1024 if you want to run `node` not run `sudo node` 
const debug = true;
const httpServer = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url, true);
  let pathName = parsedUrl.pathname;
  if (pathName==='/favicon.ico') {
    // chrome calls this to get an icon to display in the tab. I want to ignore these request. They only happen when testing in a browser,
    // not when this api is called in production by a non-browser.
    if (debug) console.log('Browser requested favicon.ico')
    response.end();
    
  } else {
    if (debug) console.log('Request on path ' + pathName);
    const elements = pathName.split('/');
    if (elements.length == 3 && elements[0] === '' &&  elements[1]==='witholdcalc') {
      const grossString = elements[2];
      const gross = Number.parseInt(grossString);
      if (isNaN(gross)) {
        response.writeHead(400).end(JSON.stringify({error:'Gross salary must be an integer. found: ' + grossString}));
      } else {
        /*
         * The computation of the amount to withold is more complicated that this, but it could still be hard coded here:
         * For simplicity, I will compute in one line:
         */
        const withold = Math.floor((gross<1000)?0:((gross-1000)*.2));
        response.writeHead(200).end(JSON.stringify({net: (gross-withold), withold: withold, elements:(debug?elements:undefined)}));
      }
    } else {
      if (debug) console.log('Invalid path was: ' + pathName,elements);
      response.writeHead(404).end();
    }
  }
});
httpServer.listen(port), () => {
  console.log(`PAYG listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
}
```

I then could execute `sudo node install.js` on my linux computer, and in a browser, hit `http://localhost/witholdcalc/6000`, and it would return {"net":5000,"withold":1000} when debug is set to false.

Comment: so could this be a substitute for the render function in express?

Comment: it would be good to separate the purpose you are doing this for, from the function of sending the file to the browser. maybe put it in a function, render(), or something like that.

Comment: @Fzs2 this is an API, designed for non-browsers to call and retrieve data, not for display in chrome or firefox.

Comment: Regarding this replacing the render function in express: express is an npm module. You don't #need# modules a lot of the time. Native node has an ability to take a http request and return a response using its (native) ```http```. My point is you don't need to use express at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Heads up for anyone attempting to serve static files without Express or any other framework:**

There is no benefit to skipping Express, in terms of performance or productivity. The only exception is to gain an understanding of how the server and client communicate with each other. Frameworks like Express abstract away all of those complexities, and beginners may not fully understand how they work.

Here is my approach to serving static files using Node.js only. Actually, the reason I did this is because a coding test I was given stipulated no framework whatsoever.

1. First, decide what the URL path for those static files should look like. I want mine to be accessible under `/assets/` path, such as `https://example.com/assets/main.css`, `https://example.com/assets/cat.jpg`.
2. Decide the REGEX for matching those URL.
   `const assetPattern = /^/assets/[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+/;

The formula above will match urls which contains `/assets/[filename].[file extension`.

3. Create a server with Node.js, taking a callback function as a parameter.

```
// ...
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(requestListener).
```

4. Extract url path, get the corresponding file path and configure your server to send the correct MIME types to the browser.

```
const path = require('path');
// ...
const requestListener = (req, response) => {
  // get the relative url for the request. For example, relative url for a request  
  // to https://example.com is /.
  const { url } = req;
  if (url.match(assetPattern)) {
  // Inside the project directory, the static files are located under the
  // /public/assets directory.
    const filePath = `./public/${url}`;
  // Get the extension name aka the string after the dot. For example, a url like 
  // https://example.com/assets/main.css will result in extension name of css.
    const extname = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase();
    const mimeTypes = {
      '.html': 'text/html',
      '.js': 'text/javascript',
      '.css': 'text/css',
      '.json': 'application/json',
      '.png': 'image/png',
      '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
      '.gif': 'image/gif',
      '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
      '.wav': 'audio/wav',
      '.mp4': 'video/mp4',
      '.woff': 'application/font-woff',
      '.ttf': 'application/font-ttf',
      '.eot': 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
      '.otf': 'application/font-otf',
      '.wasm': 'application/wasm',
    };
    const contentType = mimeTypes[extname] || 'application/octet-stream';
    staticFileHandler(req, response, filePath, contentType);
  }
}
```

5. Serve the static files with `fs` module

```
const fs = require('fs')
// ...
const staticFileHandler = (req, res, filePath, contentType) => {
  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end(`Sorry, check with the site admin for error: ${err.code}`)
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType }); // indicate the request was successful
      res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
  }
}
```