# making js and other files available to html via node.js http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a very simple web server like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, content) {
    if (err) {
      res.end('something went wrong.');
      return;
    }
    res.end(content);
  });

}).listen(8080);
console.log("Server running on port 8080.")
```

This renders my index.html without any issues, but if I try to reference another file in my index.html via a script tag for instance, the site just gets stuck, unable to find the file which exists in the server directory.

How can I make those files available to my index.html file?

Please keep in mind that I realize this can be done much more easily with `Express` but I do not wish to use `Express`. I am trying to learn how things work behind the scene. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the directory visible to public. Its is recommend to use framework while developing the Node.js application.

Here is the code below to server file without framework.

```
var basePath = __dirname;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(basePath, req.url));
    stream.on('error', function() {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    });
    stream.pipe(res);
}).listen(9999);
```

Refer : [Node itself can serve static files without express or any other module..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061080/node-itself-can-serve-static-files-without-express-or-any-other-module)

Comment: Thank you for the refer. It helps me understand the vulnerabilities of this